# running sql code in python difference between r''' and f'''

Tags: python, sql, string

I have a code like below. I noticed that i can replace `f'''` with `r'''`
what is the difference between those 2 options and when to use it?.
it seems that `r'''` when there is regex in the code?
i tried to google but didnt get any good results

```
query = f'''

with a as (
select 
some sql or hive code

from a
'''
```

Comment: There's no difference in this case. `f` is for string formatting, but you have no `{variable}` in the string. `r` is for raw strings, but you have no backslashes that need to be treated literally. You don't need `f` or `r` at all.

Comment: `f` and `r` are orthogonal; you can have a string literal prefixed with *both*, and each provides its intended effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f""` strings are strings that can be formatted. How it works: you specify the code in curly braces and the result of this code will be substituted into your string.

```
print(f"2 + 2 = {2 + 2}")  # 2 + 2 = 4
print(f"max = {max(7, 8)}")  # max = 8
```

**Notes**:

1. You won't be able to reuse the same kind of quotes as you used to designate the main string.

   `print(f"Hello, {"world!"}")  # SyntaxError`
   `print(f"Hello, {'world!'}")  # Hello, world!`
2. If you need curly brackets without formatting, add another one of the same bracket.

   `print(f"Example {{ text }}")  # Example { text }`
3. You cannot use a backslash when formatting.

   `print(f"No backslash {'\n'}")  # SyntaxError`

`r""` string is a raw string. The interpreter will treat the backslash as a regular character

```
print("Hello,\tworld!")  # Hello,   world!
print(r"Hello,\tworld!")  # Hello,\tworld!
```

Comment: thanks, you said that `You cannot use a backslash when formatting.` but this works - `print(f"Hello,\tworld!")`

Comment: @user2543622 you misunderstood: a backslash cannot be directly within curly braces